# Adding Events for all the child nodes

Tags: javascript

Why is that adding an event to the `document.querySelector('li')` works fine but 
Adding an event to the `document.getElementsByTagName('li').childNodes` 
Results in error and how to overcome this problem and attach events to all
Its child nodes successfully, I know using `childNodes` creates an array but how do we add it. Should I use a `for` loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an event to an element but not to a collection.

You can access `childNodes` from an element but not a collection.  Note that `childNodes` may include text nodes, which don't support event handlers.

What you want is **[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**, which creates a collection of elements based on a [**CSS selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

You can iterate through the collection using a `for` loop, adding event listeners along the way:

```js
var nodes= document.querySelectorAll('li > *');

for(var i = 0 ; i < nodes.length ; i++) {
  nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('You clicked ' + this.textContent);
  });
}
```

```css
li * {background: orange;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem <em>ipsum</em> dolor <strong>sit</strong> amet</li>
  <li>Consectetur <em>adipiscing</em> elit</li>
  <li>beatae <em>vitae</em> dicta <strong>sunt</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var element : document.getElementsByTagName('li')) {
  Event.observe(element, "click", function(){...});
}
```

Comment: or if you want to add to all child elements of all li tags wrap this into another for loop