# How to get text values when click if text are not inside html tag?

Tags: javascript, html

There is html on the screen that looks like this.

screen:

```
target1 target2 target3 target4
```

code:

```
<div>
  target1
  <span>target2</span>
  <span>target3</span>
  target4
</div>
```

When i click on target4,
I want to get the text "target4"

How do you approach it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563169/detect-which-word-has-been-clicked-on-within-a-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer both questions you had

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div"); // get the div wrapper
div.childNodes.forEach(function(node) { // loop over the nodes
  var text = node.textContent; // get the text
  if (node.nodeName=="#text" && text.trim()!="") { // if text and not empty 
    var span = document.createElement("span"); // wrap in a span
    span.textContent = node.textContent.trim();
    node = div.replaceChild(span,node);
  }
});
div.onclick=function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.textContent); 
}
```

```css
span { color:red }
```

```html
<div>
  target1
  <span>target2</span>
  <span>target3</span>
  target4
</div>
```

Comment: awesome! 
I didn't know you answered here yesterday.
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can get the value of your last text node, this is not a problem. Unfortunately :

> [childNodes may include text nodes, which don't support event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005551/adding-events-for-all-the-child-nodes)

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
x.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  console.log(e.currentTarget.childNodes[4].textContent)});
```

```html
<div>
  target1
  <span>target2</span>
  <span>target3</span>
  target4
</div>
```

Comment: he want to show target4 when click on target4 only.

Comment: When i click on target4, I want to get the text "target4" ==>this one does not solve this

Comment: Read the answer. `target4` is a text node and cannot have an event listener added to it. The OP can wrap your text in a span, attach an event listener to the div and capture it with `event.target`, but with the current markup what the OP is asking is not possible. If this isn't possible this is really the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

scraaapy has answered your question. But if you have the control over the HTML, then just do this:

HTML

```
<div>
  <span>target1</span>
  <span>target2</span>
  <span>target3</span>
  <span>target4</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var el = document.querySelector("div");
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.textContent);
});
```

This way, your code is much easier to maintain and work with. Hope this help!